# Error -'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, javac

Cannot able to run my java program.

I have set the java path

```
set "path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\javac.exe"
```

but its not working

> C:\Java Program>set "path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin"
>
> C:\Java Program>echo path path
>
> C:\Java Program>echo %path% C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\GoAndroy
>   Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\GoAndroy
>   Tech\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
>
> C:\Java Program>javac 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: You have to set `PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin` and `JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1`. One more thing to remember is to put the delimiter ";" between these two variables.

Comment: You need to learn how to set the path in windows from the command line, I suggest you google this for your windows version. For Windows 10 it would be `setx path "%path%; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin"`

Comment: Just as a sanity check...  You do _have_ that folder on your computer, and there _is_ a `javac.exe` in there right?

Comment: C:\>set path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\ tried like this but not working

Comment: yes.. i have javac.exe file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do like this

`set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\`

see no space arround `=`

---

If you want to make this permanent

Open `run dialog box` and enter `sysdm.cpl`

go to `advance tab -> envirnment variable`
 and then edit the `path` in system variable

If you have windows 8 or later then

- click on new and paste `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\`

Or if you have windows 7 then

- paste `;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\`

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the path to executable directly. Instead set it to the directory that holds that binary. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i tried that one also but not working  C:\>set path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\

C:\>javac
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Set java path inside environment variables:

- Go to Systems - > Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables
- Click on `Path` in User variables. If `Path` User variable doesn't exists, then create one by clicking on New in User variables
- Add `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin` in `Path` edit environment variable by clicking on `Edit` button present on right palette.
- click ok and exit.

Now, open a new command prompt and check using `javac` or `javac -version`.